# Multiple databases using routers

Tags: django, python-3.x, database, django-models, multiple-databases

I created an application with three apps account,Product and Post, i want to connect each app to different database but it is just not happening.Please tell me what i am doing wrong.This is the first time i am trying to use multiple databases.

setting.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['account.router.AccountRouter', 'Post.router.PostRouter','Product.router.ProductRouter']
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'NAME': 'a_user',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    },
    'account_db': {
        'NAME': 'account',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    },
    'post_db': {
        'NAME': 'post',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    },
    'product_db': {
        'NAME': 'product',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }
}
```

Product/router.py

```
class ProductRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {'Product',}

    def db_for_read(self, model):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to product_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'product_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to product_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'product_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'product_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'product_db'
        return None
```

Similarly Post/router.py and account/router.py

Product/models.py

```
User = get_user_model()


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30 , unique = True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(decimal_places= 2 , max_digits = 30)
    price = models.BigIntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'product_data'
```

Post/models.py

```
User = get_user_model()


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="posts",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    text = models.TextField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "posts:single",
            kwargs={
                "username": self.user.username,
                "pk": self.pk
            }
        )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        unique_together = ["user",]
        app_label = 'post_data'
```

account/models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'user_data'
```

main project dir
mayapp/router.py

```
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth and contenttypes applications.
    """
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write auth and contenttypes models go to auth_db.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'auth_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the auth or contenttypes apps is
        involved.
        """
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth and contenttypes apps only appear in the
        'auth_db' database.
        """
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'auth_db'
        return None
```

Used
python manage.py migrate --database=account_db

python manage.py migrate --database=post_db

python manage.py migrate --database=product_db

every time it migrates

Operations to perform:

Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions

Running migrations:

No migrations to apply.

```
(test) C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\tradeex_proj\myapp>python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 86, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 76, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 260, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Envs\test\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Comment: Did you create the migrations?

Comment: I ran makemigrations command it said no changes detected.But the folder for the migrations is not getting created I also ran python manage.py makemigrations appname.Stil its not getting created.

Comment: Try using `--initial`

Comment: Not working tried migrate --fake-initial

Comment: Have you tried supplying a default database?

Comment: Yeah i did but same issue is persisting. It is just not connecting database to the apps

Comment: Is it possible that there is some migrations history in db that i am not catching.